# Deployment issues regarding some resources

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2012, advanced-installer

I am having a issue regarding my deployment of my software in Visual Studio 2012. First of all I am not able to install the "InstallShield Limited Edition" through VS12 so I am currently testing out [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) instead.

Mys issue comes due to the fact that in my program I am fetching a .pdf file and modifying it and later on showing them to the user. These PDF:s is in the programs resources folder but does not follow with the installer, so my application crashes since it cannot find this. The same is for my .chm file (help file)?

My customer is using XP and when I try to publish the software directly from VS12 it works on my computer, Windows 8, but not on his computer. The application won't even start for him.

So how can I deploy my pdfs to the installer file, or why is this not accomplished already?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the PDF and CHM files are not imported automatically in the project. What type of project have you created in VS?

To add those files in the setup use the "**Edit in Advanced Installer**" button from the Advanced Installer VS extension and go to Files and Folders page. There you should add the two files in the desired folder and save the project.